# How to fix "Opened sidebar when page is loaded"?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a sidebar nav. There is a hamburger button when clicked opens nav. But when page is loaded, it is already opened. I don't want it to already opened. How do I fix this?

I am a noob in JS. I have tried value 'javascript:void(0)' in href attribute, but it didn't work.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-menu" onclick="openMenu()">&9776;
</a>
<div class="side-menu" id="side-menu">
    <a href="#" class="cross-btn" onclick="closeMenu()" style="font-size: 50px">&times;
    </a>
    <a href="#">Features</a>
    <a href="#">Pricing</a>
    <a href="#">Login</a>
</div>

<script>
    function openMenu() {
      document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "250px";
    }
    function closeMenu() {
      document.getElementById("side-menu").style.width = "0";
    }
</script>
```

**Expected result**: Sidebar nav will open only when Hamburger icon is clicked.
**Actual result**: When page is loaded, nav is already opened.

Comment: the `CSS` part ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add display:none to the style of div #side-menu:

```
<div class="side-menu" id="side-menu" style="display:none;">
```

And instead of resizing the width of #side-menu, change the display to block when the menu is clicked, and back to none when the cross sign is clicked.

```
function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("side-menu").style.display = "block";
}

function closeMenu() {
  document.getElementById("side-menu").style.display = "none";
}
```

The full code:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="click-menu" onclick="openMenu()">&#9776;</a>
<div class="side-menu" id="side-menu" style="display:none;">
  <a href="#" class="cross-btn" onclick="closeMenu()" style="font-size: 50pxl">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Features</a>
  <a href="#">Pricing</a>
  <a href="#">Login</a>
</div>

<script>
  function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("side-menu").style.display = "block";
  }
  function closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById("side-menu").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

P.S. Also change `&9776;` to `&#9776;`

Comment: but what if the `#side-menu` has a `transition` ? No animation will occur.